# convert api response to map Angular 16

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

If i have a json response from a java server that looks like this

```
{
  "summary": {
    
  },
  "runs": {
    "key_1": {
      "object_1": {
        
      },
      "object_2": {
        
      }
    },
    "key_2": {
      "object_1": {
        
      },
      "object_2": {
        
      }
    }
  }
}
```

service looks like this

```
public getDetailsV2(id: number): Observable<MyClass> {
    return this.httpClient.get<SimulationDetailedResponseV2>(
      'url_to_endpoint'
    );
  }
```

calling it like this:

```
this.service.getDetailsV2(1).subscribe({
      next: (details) => {
        this.details = details;
      }
    });
```

but when i call any map methods on `this.details` I get errors
for example to get the first entry when I do:
`this.details.runs.entries().next().value;`
I get:
`ERROR TypeError: this.details.runs.entries is not a function`

and MyClass looks like this

```
export class MyClass {
  runs: Map<string, AnotherObject>;
}
```

Why isn't the response.runs converted to map automatically? How can I convert it manually?

Comment: please share the expected output!

Comment: What is the type of `this.details.runs` if you log it to the console?

Comment: @NarenMurali expected output is being able to call map methods on the`this.details.runs`

@Sean it prints object not map

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below code, we can do `Object.entries` and convert the object into a map, after that your code works, javascript does not do this automatically, we need to access the individual properties of an object.

```js
const data = {
  "summary": {
        "test": 1,
  },
  "runs": {
    "key_1": {
      "object_1": {
        "test": 1,
      },
      "object_2": {
        "test": 1,
      }
    },
    "key_2": {
      "object_1": {
        "test": 1,
      },
      "object_2": {
        "test": 1,
      }
    }
  }
};

const neededMap = new Map(Object.entries(data.runs));
console.log(neededMap.entries().next().value);
```

So applying this snippet to your code will look like!

```
this.service.getDetailsV2(1).subscribe({
  next: (details) => {
    details.runs = new Map(Object.entries(details.runs));
    this.details = details;
  }
});
```